# nsnotification trouble

Tags: iphone, ios, nsnotificationcenter

So I have a method:

```
-(void)didLoginWithAccount(MyAccount *)account
```

And I added an observer to this method like

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didLoginWithAccount:)];
```

And my question is, when I post Notification, how can I pass a MyAccount object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get a notification callback, the notification object is passed, and not the object explicitly.

Step 1, Register:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didLoginWithAccount:) name:@"MyCustomNotification" object:nil];
```

Step 2, Post:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyCustomNotification" object:myAccount];
```

Step 3, Recieve:

```
- (void)didLoginWithAccount:(NSNotification *)notification {
    MyAccount *myAccount = (MyAccount *)[notification object];
}
```